# Indefinite article with fuel and pleasure

Tags: indefinite-articles

> Is food fuel or pleasure for you?

Do we need indefinite article in the question?
Can we really count pleasure/pleasures or fuel/fuels?
Your considerations please!

Comment: You definitely need an indefinite article in _your_ question.

Comment: I have found a lot of resources where with no article, e.g.: _Obviously, food is fuel for your body, and filling your tank with the quantity and quality of food your body needs will help you operate at your best. “Running on fumes” or regularly filling up with foods that are low on nutrition will leave you feeling lackluster. But food is also pleasure._https://www.seattletimes.com/

Comment: "Do we need **an** indefinite article in the question?" And after {e.g.} we normally expect an example.

Comment: One more please:_In my opinion, not only food is fuel, do some sport is fuel too_https://www.language-exchanges.org/blog/food-fuel-or-pleasure

Comment: One more please: _technically, food is just fuel for living_[https://zenhabits.net/its-time-for-a-new-relationship-with-food/]

Comment: So Mr./Ms. Rattler please don't be quick with your conclusions...

Comment: It is not my personal opinion: you _need_ an article in that sentence.

Comment: Whose opinion is that then?))) How can you explain dozens of examples with no article? Total illiteracy?

Comment: The point is not in being a native English speaker but in giving correct answers).

Comment: @anna299 - Rattler was referring to your question “***Do we need indefinite article in the question?***”  which does indeed need be “*Do we need **an** indefinite article...*”.

Comment: You can include "a" before "fuel" and "pleasure" or not -- it's a style issue (and to some degree a matter of subtle implications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do we need indefinite article in the question?**

No. "Is food fuel or pleasure for you?" is correct, and does not require an indefinite article.

**Can we really count pleasure/pleasures or fuel/fuels?**

Yes, both are countable words with plural forms. However, in both cases, the countable form has a slightly different meaning to the uncountable form.

A fuel (countable) is a type of fuel (uncountable). A pleasure (countable) is an example of something that gives us pleasure (uncountable). It's like to how "cheese" is usually uncountable, but we can say, "Mozzarella is *a cheese* from Italy." Some examples:

- There isn't enough fuel in the car to get home. (uncountable)
- Gasoline is a fuel commonly used in cars. (countable)
- I get so much pleasure from painting. (uncountable)
- It was a pleasure meeting you. (countable)
- Watching a child sleep is one of the many pleasures of parenthood. (countable)

Comment: Thank you! I have come across both: "Is food (a) fuel or (a) pleasure for you?"

Comment: Great! Remember to upvote answers you like and hopefully select one as satisfactory if you feel it answers your question completely